# php gethostbyname() extremely slow on windows

Tags: php, dns, resolve, gethostbyname

I'am tryting to implement multy-threaded script (php7+phtreads v3) to get information about a large amount of domains. However, the most important thing is to find out domain's IP. I found that gethostbyname() works very slow and it's a bottleneck of the code. Is there a way to somehow increase perfomance? Thank you.

Comment: So what's your local name server configuration? Not much you can do for speedying up queries to thousands of hostnames, https://howdns.works/

Comment: @mario, I'am using providers DNS. Is there any kind of solution to somehow speed up this task? Thanks for link, lol.